# How to use split() to remove all delimiters from a sentence in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

```
String text = "Good morning. Have a good class. " +
"Have a good visit. Have fun!";
String[] words = text.split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){");
```

This `split` method is provided in text book, meant to remove all the delimiters in the sentence as well as white space character but clearly it is not working and throws a regex exception to my disappointment....I am wondering what could we do here to make it work? The requirement is after the `split` method, everything in the `String[] words are either just English words without any delimiters attaching to it or whitespace character! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You forgot to close your character class. Add `]` at the end of your regex. You can also add `+` to let it find one or more of continuous delimiters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing closing `]` in your character class:

```
String[] words = text.split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){]");
```

btw you can just do (and it is better option):

```
String[] words = text.split("\\W+");
```

to split on any non-word character.

Comment: `\\W` may not be best idea. It will split also on `'` so `Don't be late!` will end up with `Don` `t`...

Comment: Hmm in that case probably `[\\W&&[^\"']]` will be better regex for split.

Comment: Yes, that could do the trick, but lets maybe not confuse OP who seems to be new to regex :)

Comment: LOL, thx guys. Appreciate your helps. I am really new to regex and that just looks really weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` is NOT for removing characters. It is used to divide the `String` into smaller substrings.

Example:

```
String s = "This is a string!";
String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
```

Split will have used the String " " (one space character) as a delimiter to, well, split the string. As a result, the array `tokens` will look something like

```
{"This", "is", "a", "string!"}
```

If you want to remove characters, try taking a look at [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))